# How to avoid subquery in FROM clause to translate SQL query into hibernate query?

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a rather simple query that works in standard SQL, but doesn't in HQL :

```
SELECT id 
FROM ( SELECT COUNT(*) as rows, 
              MESSAGES_ID as id 
       FROM motcles_message mm 
       WHERE motcle IN :keyWords 
       GROUP BY MESSAGES_ID) a 
WHERE a.rows = :size
```

Is there any way for me to avoid using a subquery in the FROM statement since HQL doesn't support it ?
I know it can use subqueries in SELECT and WHERE clauses, but I can't find a solution.

Comment: Are you running MySQL or SQLServer? These are two different database products, you should be tagging only one.

Comment: @GMB My bad it's only MySQL, I removed the incorrect tag

Comment: Now I'm confused the question looked like it was about HQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT MESSAGES_ID as id 
FROM motcles_message mm 
WHERE motcle IN :keyWords 
GROUP BY MESSAGES_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = :size
```